Why is my model behaving like different objects?
I want to animate this character.
When working with it, I noticed that even though I used Boolean join, the different objects are still "separate".
In the side menu on the right, I can see them as different objects. When I tried using the join shortcut (Ctrl + J) it says there are no separated objects.

See the thin, black squares around my shapes. What are they?
Or does the fact that I have the meshes as separate objects and as a single object (somehow!) fine?

Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload images or gifs, along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Is this a question about Blender? As it stands this sounds like an issue with some unknown third part software
